# Is there a way to use a variable in nginx config?

Tags: nginx

In my nginx configuration file there're several identical values. Is there any way to specify a variable(s) or constant(s) for those in the beginning of a nginx config file, once, in order then to  refer to it via a variable or constant?

If there's a way of achiving that via env. variables, it won't work for me. A variable will need to be set in an nginx file itself.

Comment: Do you mean like in this old post? I am not sure why you say it will not work: https://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf

Comment: Be a little more specific, can you give a code snippit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is `set $variable_name variable_value;`

Then you can reference `$variable_name` in subsequent lines of the Nginx config.

See more [here](https://cheat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nginx.html#variables-in-configuration-files).

It is a feature of the **rewrite module** and not a feature of Nginx itself -- this means you ***must*** have the rewrite module enabled in order for this to work.

If you install the `nginx-extras` package, this is enabled by default.

You can read more about the `ngx_http_rewrite_module` [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).

Comment: I think here is a more detailed response that cover interesting aspects. https://serverfault.com/questions/644892/nginx-set-variable-in-location/644898#644898